# vuejs: insert spans into text - common practice

Tags: vuejs2

using vue.js I'm wondering what is considered the best way to insert `span` elements into a `text` at multiple given `positions`? Specifically, in a simplified example, I have:

```
 text = "This is a random text. It goes on and on..."
 positions = [0, 5, 17]
 span_templ = '<span class="some_class" />' <-- closed span for sake of simplicity
```

The workflow is: the user clicks on a button, some RESTful request is sent to a server, which returns both `text` and `positions`. A `<p>` shall be updated with the text but with inserted `<span>` elements.

I'm relatively new to vue.js, so I'm wondering what is more typical in vue.js: rather do the String update in the template `{{ ... }}` itself or would you first update the String in plan JS and then simply refer to the String in the moustache part?

Comment: You could use a computed property: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `v-html` and pass the HTML string as prop.

Example use: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

API doc: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html